# result of passing argv variable to main in this format main( int argc, char const * argv )

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, argv

I am trying to figure out what will be result of passing argv variable to main in this format.
main( int argc, char const * argv ).

I know right way of using it is main( int argc, char const **argv)
or main( int argc, char const *argv[]).

Here is my code snippet,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main( int argc, char const * argv ) {
        for( int i = 0; i < argc; ++i ) {
               printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
        }
}
```

Here is output,

> $ ./a.exe
>
> ..
>
> $ ./a.exe 1
>
> 2
>
> ....
>
> $ ./a.exe 1 2
>
> 2
>
> ...

Does it fetch from whatever, argv points? Why does it terminate before even reaching argc.

Comment: It's actually not the right way unless your implementation allows it. The C standard only specifies `argv` as a buffer of pointers to **non-const** strings.

Comment: In your code as written, `argv[i]` will be a `char` value. In the `printf` call, that will be promoted to an `int` value. However, the `printf` function is expecting a valid pointer to a null-terminated sequence of `char` at that position, not some bogus pointer value.

Answer (score 2):

It causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as the supplied type and the expected type does not match thereby this is a clear case of constraint violation.

Quoting `C11`, chapter chapter §5.1.2.2.1/p2, (*emphasis mine*)

> If they are declared, the parameters to the main function shall obey the following
>   constraints:
>
> - ...
> - If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the array members `argv[0]` through
>     `argv[argc-1]` inclusive shall contain **pointers to strings**, which are given
>     implementation-defined values by the host environment prior to program startup

You can re-write `char * argv[]` as `char **argv` <sup>NOTE</sup> considering the array decay property, but a `char *[]` and a `char *` are not compatible in any way.

---

NOTE:

Quoting `C11`, chapter §5.1.2.2.1, footnote 10)

> Thus, `int` can be replaced by a typedef name defined as `int`, or the type of `argv` can be written as
>   `char ** argv`, and so on.

Comment: Additionally, the `printf` call has undefined behavior because the types of the arguments differ from those specified by the format specifier string.